# Executing a stored procedure on remote database

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, permissions

I have 2 databases on the same server. DB-A and DB-B. DB-B has a user that has read and write access to database B. I would like to grant the user in DB-B execute permissions to 2 stored procedures in database A. I was able to do this when the databases were on seperate servers by setting up a linked server, and mapping a linked login. I am having trouble with this when the databases are on the same server. Can someone please tell me how I can accomplish this task.

Thanks,
James

Comment: I have tried creating a user in each database. user in database A with dbo rights to that database and a user in database b with db_reader and deny_write then i tried to exec the sproc on database a while logged in as the user from db b to no avail. i also tried logging in as user on db b and executing the proc on A just using the 4 part name but that made no sense since i would assume user b would need the credentials for a linked login to db a that has execute permissions on the sproc in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create linked logins or anything like that. For a local database you can just add the user to DB_A from the login, then grant exec to the two procedures. First:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_A;
GO
CREATE DATABASE DB_B;
GO

-- create a login:
CREATE LOGIN DBB_Owner WITH PASSWORD = 'foo', 
  DEFAULT_DATABASE = DB_B,
  CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO

-- make DBB_Owner the DB_B owner:
-- step is not necessary, just trying to match your scenario
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DB_B TO DBB_Owner;
GO

USE DB_A;
GO

-- create a local user from the server login:
CREATE USER DBB_Owner FROM LOGIN DBB_Owner;
GO
```

Now create three procedures. For the first two, give explicit exec rights to DBB_Owner, and don't allow them any permissions on the third.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc1
AS
    SELECT 'Yes! - from Proc1';
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc2
AS
    SELECT 'Yes! - from Proc2';
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc3
AS
    SELECT 'No! - from Proc3';
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.Proc1 TO DBB_Owner;
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.Proc2 TO DBB_Owner;
```

Now connect to the server as `DBB_Owner` with the password `foo`, and try to execute the three procedures:

```
EXEC DB_A.dbo.Proc1;
EXEC DB_A.dbo.Proc2;
EXEC DB_A.dbo.Proc3;

--or

USE DB_A;
EXEC dbo.Proc1;
EXEC dbo.Proc2;
EXEC dbo.Proc3;
```

Results:

```
Yes! - from Proc1
Yes! - from Proc2
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure Proc3, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'Proc3', database 'DB_A', schema 'dbo'.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Just so I understand what is going on under the hood the user that is being created from the login essentially just provides a gateway so that login can be granted the right to explicitly execute things on the other database. I am assuming if you setup the account like that and didn't add any specific grants the account would not be able to do anything?

Comment: basically i need to make sure that DBB_Owner can do anything on DB_B, and yet can ONLY run the 2 sprocs on DB_A. The user should not be able to write to any tables on DB_A, or modify anything, should only be able to execute the sprocs and have read only access to the 2 tables the sprocs touch.

Comment: You may also want to look at the `EXECUTE AS OWNER` option for the procedures. You can explicitly deny certain things from the user but in most cases this shouldn't be necessary - adding them to the database only adds them to the public role, and unless you've granted all permissions on all objects to public, this shouldn't be a concern. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx